# MacBook Air storage suddenly full of movies

Tags: macos, storage

Last night a "storage almost full" message popped up on my screen and it says I have 73GB worth of movies, but I can't find any. I have no iMovies or Photobooth videos, and no real movie downloads, and just 2 small iPhoto videos.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this graph get stuck in the wrong ways many times. What does Finder say for free space on that drive? If you really only have 1.44 GB left, the system will be shutting down and not able to work properly. If there's more space, then we can poke into spotlight which creates the colors in that image.

Comment: Use something like [DaisyDisk](http://daisydisk.com) to determine where the usage is.